# How to host domain name on a separate server and subdomain on Smarter ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, dns, subdomain, netlify

I currently have a website and web application running on smarterasp.net. The web application was built using Microsoft ASP.net using SQL database. The website was built using Gatsby JS with WordPress as a headless CMS. Due to the fact that I need to use a build hook to trigger automatic build and redeployment whenever updates are made to the WordPress CMS, there is a need to use Netlify for that since SmarterASP doesn't support that.

I plan to use domain.com for the actual website, app.domain.com for the web application, and wordpress.domain.com for the remote WordPress site.

Both the web application and WordPress will be hosted on SmarterASP while only the website will be hosted on Netlify.com.

How do I go through with it? Any guide will be sincerely appreciated.

There is a guide here but I don't really understand it:
https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1552/how-do-i-add-a-subdomain-name-while-having-my-main-domain-name-hosted-else-where.aspx?KBSearchID=926268

Comment: Of course you can. For example your domain is pointing to Smarter name server. So, in order to host Gatsby JS on Netlify, please just create subdomain for example Gatsby.yourdomain.com and then you can point your A record to Netlify IP address.

Comment: @MarkSpencer, I understand it now. Thank you